# Gnome 3 screwed up Unity, especially Nautilus

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, nautilus

I wanted to try gnome 3 in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (which had unity). I installed gnome 3 alongside unity; tried it; didn't like it. So, I uninstalled gnome 3 environment. But now my unity is not working properly.

1. Ubuntu freezes whenever I try to minimize or close an app, especially file manager(Nautilus).
2. I cannot keep a desktop background. No matter what I try, I cannot change the default background.
3. Fonts, files and folder spacing hasn't changed from gnome default.
4. GNU Grub screen now has turned grey in color (a gnome default), which was previously purple in colour

I have tried all solutions that is presented in  this site. None worked. Someone please give me a solution.

Part Solution:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

This solved my wallpaper problem.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem!

Comment: Did you install 'gnome3' from ubuntu repos or from a ppa?

Comment: Ubuntu repository

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here is a solution.

Looking through dconf-editor, I realised that gnome is still in control (I do not know how!). Nautilus is not found under apps, anymore. But, rather under gnome.

There are answers suggesting that the minimize-freeze problem can be solved by enabling desktop icons to be shown. So, I tried it by enabling desktop icons under gnome/nautilus/desktop. But that didn't work. To be precise there was no option enable desktop icons. There were only options to enable individual icons such as home, network etc...

After rummaging for a while I found it under gnome/desktop/background. By enabling desktop icons here, the minimize-freeze problem was solved.

Unity Tweak Tool revealed that default fonts were set to gnome default fonts. You can manually set it to Unity default fonts. Note that, 'Restore Default' button doesn't switch to unity font as default is gnome font.